# Prove that a line is a polyhedral set (can be made by a finite number of inequalities)

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, convex-optimization, linear-programming

I know that to prove this I have to shown that a set of finite inequalities make a line in $\mathbb R^n$  that is

$$ L = \{  x_0 + \lambda d : \lambda \in \mathbb R^n \} $$

But can we say a line is the intersection of 3 hyperplanes in $\mathbb R^n$ (since each hyperplane can be shown with 2 inequalities). Can we say the same things about a half-line (that is when $ \lambda \geq 0 $)?

Comment: No. The intersection of affine sets is affine, in particular, the intersection must either be a point or (at least) contain a line. An affine set is a translate of a linear subspace (there are other characterisations).

Comment: What about a line? How can we show that for a line formally?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Show what for a line?

Comment: That it is equivalent to the points in a system of linear inequalities in Rn

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that $d \neq 0$ below:

Let $v_2,...,v_n$ form a basis for $(\operatorname{sp}\{d\})^\bot$.

Define $H_k = \{x| \langle v_k, x-x_0 \rangle = 0 \}$.

Then $L= \cap_k H_k$.

Suppose $x \in L$, then $x=x_0+\lambda d$, and it is easy to check that $x \in H_k$ for all $k$.

In general, given any $x$, there are unique $\lambda, \alpha_k$ such that $x=x_0+\lambda d + \sum_k \alpha_k v_k$.

Suppose $x \in H_k$, then we must have $\alpha_k = 0$.

Hence if $x \in \cap_k H_k$, then $x=x_0 + \lambda d$ and so $x \in L$.